# Bitnami AJAX error

Tags: php, jquery, bitnami

I have a Bitnami server installed on my Windows machine. My local site has an issue with jQuery post. I get a 500 internal server error when trying to access a PHP file. Below is the code and the error in my Chrome console. Is this a permissions error? If so, how do I resolve this?

This function is called from an onchange event in my form. It displays the correct state according to zip code. It is having trouble accessing the post_zip.php file.

```
function GetStateByZip(zip) {

    $.post('../post_zip.php', {         
        Zip: zip,
        submit: 'yes'}, function(data) {

        if(data.match('success')) {

            $('#State').fadeIn('fast');
            var state = data.substring(7);

            $('#State').val(state);

        } else {

            $('#State').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#State').val("");
            $('#responseBox').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#response').html("Zip code is not valid.").fadeIn('slow');
            FadeMsg();
        }
    }, 'text');

THIS IS THE ERROR
POST http://localhost/iss/contact/post_zip.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.c.send @ jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
f.each.f.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
GetStateByZip @ (index):95
onchange @ (index):38
```

Comment: The 500 error indicates that the problem is somewhere on the server side. Maybe try a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your php script to verify that the data is being posted correctly

Comment: It's not reaching the file at all.

Comment: File path is definitely correct?

Comment: Try navigating to this url `http://localhost/iss/contact/post_zip.php?test=true` and add this line to the top of your php `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: The path is correct and the testing irrelevant because it's getting the 500 error. It's unable to access the file.

Comment: Did you try the last suggestion

Comment: Yes. I'm familiar with PHP testing.

Comment: I discovered the problem. There is another database connection required and the config file needed to reflect the database location.